# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON usanso class-transformer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Tengo el siguiente error en mi api con nestjs usando typescript y node, al intentar parsear una varibale en un archivo dto con la el paquete de class-transformer

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 4\n    at JSON.parse**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

import { Transform } from "class-transformer";
import {  IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

```
export class GetAllKpiDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()

  @Transform((item): object  => {
  return item.obj.idFranquicias  = JSON.parse(item.value)
  })
  idFranquicias:number[];
}
```

***El problema esta en esta linea**

```
return item.obj.idFranquicias  = JSON.parse(item.value)
```

Lo que envio con el postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería últil que colocaras un [mcve], es decir, muestras solo parte del código pero no explicas del todo la funcionalidad del código. ¿Podrías colocar un ejemplo de lo que tratas de convertir? Es decir, que es lo que intentas covertir de `a -> b`, en otras palabras, entrada y salida esperada.

Comment: Adicionalmente, bienvenido a [es.so], recuerda que puedes hacer el [tour] para  obtener consejos útiles sobre esta plataforma y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes leer [ask] para mejorar esta y otras futuras preguntas, recuerda que siempre puedes [edit] tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. Saludos.